# jquery select something of the page in an iframe

Tags: jquery, parent

I got a page like this:

```
=========================================
|       PARENT!                         |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|            ===============            |
|            |    iframe   |            |
|            ===============            |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|========================================
```

is there any jQuery possible to select something in the parent window?

The pages are in different domains.

Comment: Can you please let us know if the content in the iframe is in the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: the content in iframe is on other domain, but i don't think this matters

Comment: I'm afraid that _does_ matter. Javascript can't access stuff on another domain. You might want to google 'cross domain javascript' or 'javascript same domain policy' (the 'XSS' I mentioned previously is not specifically what I meant). I'm afraid that what you're trying to do is impossible (unless you control the other domain as well, there's no influencing that page's content)

Comment: It cannot be done if the pages are not in same domain. Even if you control both the domains, you can't directly access the other site's DOM like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *as long as the iframe is in the same domain as the parent* the following works:

```
$('#idInParent', window.parent.document);
```

---

**Updated:** to make clear the fact that this requires same domain